Animate motions one after the other
I'm trying to animate motions of a circle moving along edges (SVG paths) in a graph.
It looks like I don't understand the dur attribute of motions: even if I create and append a second motion after the first one ended, with its duration set to 2 seconds, then nothing happens. If I set its duration to 4 seconds instead, then the animation starts in the middle of the path, as if 2 seconds had already elapsed.
It feels like dur is a duration since the page was loaded?


<svg width="300" height="200">
    <defs>
        <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto">
            <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#f00" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="175" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="175" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    <path id="edge1" d="M70,50 Q125,0 180,90" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
    <path id="edge2" d="M70,175 Q125,125 180,100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
    <circle id="animCircle" r="10" fill="blue">
        <animateMotion repeatCount="1">
            <mpath href="#edge1" />
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const animCircle = document.getElementById('animCircle');

    // Function to create animateMotion elements dynamically
    function createAnimateMotion(pathId, dur) {
      const animElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animateMotion');
      animElement.setAttribute('dur', dur);
      animElement.setAttribute('repeatCount', '1');

      const mpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'mpath');
      mpath.setAttribute('href', pathId);

      animElement.appendChild(mpath);

      return animElement;
    }

    // Initially set the animation along the first edge
    const firstAnim = createAnimateMotion('#edge1', '2s');
    animCircle.appendChild(firstAnim);

    firstAnim.addEventListener('endEvent', function() {
      // Remove the first animation
      animCircle.removeChild(firstAnim);

      // Set the animation along the second edge
      const secondAnim = createAnimateMotion('#edge2', '4s');
      animCircle.appendChild(secondAnim);
    });
  });
</script>



How do I create my animateMotion elements so that they play one after the other, without depending on the time already elapsed?

There's an implicit start and that is from the start of any animation. I.e. animations have a timeline and the timeline advances as you play the animations. You could always start one animation from the end event of the previous one (but you'd have to create all the animations upfront so as not to miss the events).

Thanks. Yes I see it in the docs now (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin), the dur docs aren't clear about that. I see begin accepts many different values, like "edge1.endEvent", but ideally I would like to decorrelate all animations, since I want to be able to skip forward/backward and play any animation "now" (but always only one at a time).

Isn't there a way to set the begin attribute to "now"? I tried passing a <wallclock-sync-value> with animElement.setAttribute('begin', 'wallclock((new Date()).toISOString())'); but that looks terrible and it doesn't work, and I'm not sure why.

Can you write you code in StackOverflow Snippet syntax With the [<>] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Sure, done. Nothing moved in the editor though, whether I put the Javascript code in the Javascript pane or the HTML one, with or without wrapping it in the DOMContentLoaded event listener :/

Why don't you try to create as many separated animations as you need? Then you can trigger them to start by too many events or actions you can choose from (onClick, onHover, rtc). Once you got it working as expected, then try to join them in a single everything.

I'm not sure to understand your suggestion. If I create the animations ahead of time, I either have to schedule the time at which they begin (which I can't, since each could be replayed at any moment given user inputs), or I have to set the begin attribute when triggering the animation. In that case, why wasting memory by initializing animations ahead of time? I have potentially a ton of events to render. Happy to try and elaborate but it would feel like asking you to do my "homework" ^^

For now I'm computing a time delta to use as value for begin:
const started = new Date().getTime();
const animCircle = document.getElementById('animCircle');

// Function to create animateMotion elements dynamically
function createAnimateMotion(pathId, dur) {
    var animElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animateMotion');
    animElement.setAttribute('dur', dur);
    animElement.setAttribute('repeatCount', '1');
    const delta = (new Date().getTime() - started) / 1000;
    animElement.setAttribute('begin', delta);

    var mpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'mpath');
    mpath.setAttribute('href', pathId);

    animElement.appendChild(mpath);

    return animElement;
}

This should ensure that an animation starts almost exactly when it is created with createAnimateMotion.

You can queue up all animations inside the <animateMotion> element, and remove them one by one using the repeat event


const animateMotion = animCircle.firstElementChild;

animateMotion.onrepeat = () => {
  animateMotion.removeChild(animateMotion.firstElementChild);
};
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="9" markerHeight="6" refX="9" refY="3" orient="auto">
      <path d="M0 0 0 6 9 3" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="20" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="175" r="20" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="175" r="20" />
  </g>
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" marker-end="url(#arrow)">
    <path id="edge1" d="M70 50Q125 0 180 90" />
    <path id="edge2" d="M70 175q55-50 110-75" />
  </g>
  <circle id="animCircle" r="10" fill="blue">
    <animateMotion repeatCount="2" dur="2" fill="freeze">
      <mpath href="#edge1" />
      <mpath href="#edge2" />
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
</svg>



This approach requires you to set the repeatCount to the number of animations you want to play, and won't work for indefinite (infinitely looping) animations.
You can also inline this function if this is all you need
<animateMotion repeatCount="2" dur="2" fill="freeze" onrepeat="this.removeChild(this.firstElementChild)">

Here's a hacky CSS solution with different trade-offs:


#animCircle {
  animation: move 4s 1 linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%, 50.001% { offset-distance: 0% }
  50%, 100% { offset-distance: 100% }
  0%, 50% { offset-path: url(#edge1) }
  50.001%, 100% { offset-path: url(#edge2) }
}
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="9" markerHeight="6" refX="9" refY="3" orient="auto">
      <path d="M0 0 0 6 9 3" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="20" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="175" r="20" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="175" r="20" />
  </g>
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" marker-end="url(#arrow)">
    <path id="edge1" d="M70 50Q125 0 180 90" />
    <path id="edge2" d="M70 175q55-50 110-75" />
  </g>
  <circle id="animCircle" r="10" fill="blue" />
</svg>




Interesting, thanks. However there seems to be a problem: the dot is moving twice along the first edge, and never along the second edge.

Oops, I forgot to test this in different browsers. Seems like the first solution doesn't work in Safari and the second one doesn't work in Firefox :P

You could define a third path (which combines the other two) in <defs>, and use that as the source for the <mpath>, but that's yet another workaround
